# unable to render Json string on client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jquery, json.net

ascx.cs

```
protected string BindData()
   {
    List<Product> products = product.GetRepeaterData(prod);
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products);
     return json;
   }
```

ascx

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function doSomething() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ProgramListSimple.aspx/BindData",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
 };
```

I am not able to see any alert ..I dont know if the ajax function is doing what it is suppose to do..this code is for user control & not on the aspx page does that matter? while debugging I am able to see the serialized data in json string. Its just that its not rendering on the client side....working on it since morning now I need some help please..any examples or any doc can also be useful..

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` and you'll be able to see the entire JSON object in your debugger console. `alert()` can only show strings.

Comment: @Blazemonger not working ... I cant see it even in console

Comment: This suggests an empty file is being returned by `/ProgramListSimple.aspx/BindData`, then.`success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }` should be showing you whatever that script would normally display.

Comment: @Blazemonger any way to debug it?

Comment: [Are you sure your JSON is valid?](http://jsonlint.org/)

Comment: I can see the data coming in in the json string while debuging...I don't know any other way to check if its valid or not....

Comment: The problem is the PageMethod declaration, it's not static and it's not public. In order to debug it I strongly recommend you to install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: ok now I see a 404 in fiddler..

Comment: my page is ascx & I am creating the url on the fly using an CMS tool ..so what will be the url property for the method?

Comment: Give it a try and change your pagemethod declaration as: `public static string BindData()`

Comment: PageMethods can only be **inside an ASPX page, and must be static and public**, if this does not fit your requirements, then use either an ASMX, WCF, WCF REST or Web API service

Comment: @Jupao l how can I use the ASMX ?? Is there any other way of achieving this result?

Comment: I have several working examples on [my Github site](https://github.com/jupaol/LearningProjects/tree/master/VS%202012/src/WebForms/MSTS%2070-515/Msts/Topics/Chapter10%20-%20Services%20and%20Handlers/Lesson02%20-%20XML%20Services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new aspx page. Transfered all the code behind logic to the aspx.cs from ascx.cs. The just called the url of the aspx page from my ascx page using ajax callback

```
        type: "GET",
        url:'<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/ProgramListSimpledetail.aspx") %>',
        data: dataObject,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
```

I just added a small part of the fix that is very important for this to work other then this there were bunch of things that were added to make the ascx page inherit the properties from the apsx page.... but I think that was mainly related to my code...so I hope this helps someone in future...thanks for all those who tried to contribute..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `d` property

```
alert(msg.d);
```

If you are using Chrome or Firefox to debug use the following to inspect a JavaScript object:

```
console.log("%o", msg);
```

In Chrome press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to show the developer console

Comment: console.log("%o", msg);
ReferenceError: msg is not defined  I got this error message in console

Comment: Did u place that line **instead** of the `alert("msg");` right under the `success` function??

Comment: @Scorpio, did you add that `console.log` to _inside_ the `success` handler?

Comment: yes I did success: function (msg) {

                console.log("%o", msg);
            }

Comment: is my Binding function wrong???I means does it need to be a static method or something??

Comment: I am sorry I change it..its string

Comment: Your method (**PageMethod**) should be `static` and `public`, like this: `public static string BindData()`